# jQuery Ajax throwing: TypeError: this is undefined

Tags: jquery

```
var submitAjax = {
    url: "processor.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {  },
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
        alert("Thanks ! We're excited and we'll keep you up to date with all the progress !");
    }
};

jQuery.ajax(submitAjax);
```

On this call, I get the error: TypeError: this is undefined. At this point I have added a few key=>value pieces to submitAjax.data and done alerts on all elements of the ajax variable and have been successful.

This is the jquery libary I'm referencing from Google's CDN: 1.8.2

Comment: at which line you're getting the "TypeError: this is undefined" error?

Comment: TypeError: this is undefined
()main.js (line 11)
f()jquery.min.js (line 130)
d()jquery.min.js (line 130)
()jquery.min.js (line 130)
()jquery.min.js (line 29)
d()jquery.min.js (line 130)
()jquery.min.js (line 130)
()jquery.min.js (line 122)
[Break On This Error]  

...at())&&Jd(this.lng(),a.lng())});H.lat=Yc("Xa");H.lng=Yc("Ya");function ge(a,b){v...

Comment: main.js is the google maps api js... the issue happens when clicking a button inside an infowindow. It doesn't appear that ajax is ever called. Additionally, if I run the ajax submit line in the console, i get the same error.

Comment: so are you saying that even if the ajax code above is not called you are still getting the same error?

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me as well...
The problem is due to some objects provided by the google map API put into the ajax data. You have to convert them to your own javascript objects.